# HostGator MVC Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

I am trying to upload my ASP.NET MVC app to hostgator but I keep receiving this error:

**Security Exception**

**Description:** The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

**Exception Details:** System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +166
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +100
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +272
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, RuntimeAssembly asm, SecurityAction action) +55
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +39
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +32
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid() +10
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection ps) +2085
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash() +107
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64 cachedHash) +465
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64 cachedHash) +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +132
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

I try to resolve it by adding `<trust level="Full"/>` but once I do I receive another error.

**Configuration Error**

**Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

**Parser Error Message:** This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  from an inherited configuration file.

**Source Error:**

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

It says the error is on the same line as what i just added (`<trust level="Full"/>`). It just keeps going in circles and I don't know what else to do. If anyone has any ideas it would be a huge help. Thank you!

Comment: Did u solve this issue?

Comment: If i remember correctly the issue came down to MVC was not supported for the package i was using. I ended up switching to create and angular 5 application instead.

Comment: Yeah. I spoke with the HostGator team. After having chat with them for sixth time on daily basis, they solved the issue. The issue was from their side